# Error: This environment's XHR implementation cannot support binary transfer

Tags: react-native, xmlhttprequest

This work is on react native.
I have created a secret client (secret blockchain client).
But when I am trying to perform transaction, getting the following error:
Error: This environment's XHR implementation cannot support binary transfer.

here is my code snippet:

```
const tx = await clientt.tx.bank.send(
{
  amount: [{amount: '3000000', denom: 'uscrt'}],
  fromAddress: wallet.address,
  toAddress: recipient, // Set recipient to sender for testing
},
{
  gasLimit: 20_000,
  gasPriceInFeeDenom: 0.25,
  memo: 'send tokens example',
},
```

);